# excel half doughnut chart

Tags: excel, graph

I am trying to recreate a graph like this one in Excel [image]

I feel the "doughnut" type is the most appropriate - but I can't figure out how to get the graph to display just half a circle. Does the feature exist at all in Excel (which I assume) or what would be the best way to do?

Comment: This question is better suited to SuperUser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your data, make the "total" of everything part of the chart's source data, which would make the total be half the total pie chart. Then go to chart format, rotate first slice 270° to get the total on the bottom, then change the fill color to "no fill" for the total, and it will essentially look like a half circle chart. Now, in the legend (if visible), click on "total" and delete it from the legend.